# What lookup is appropriate for a matrix of data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a 'points matrix' the idea is, a sales person sells an item to a business, dependant on what product and the date it was booked (creation date) an amount of points is allocated.

'Product 1 +', 'Product 2 +', 'Product 3+' are the same products as product 1, 2 and 3. However they become + when they meet the criteria of being new (Column 'New' = YES).

What is the best way to pull through the correct points when following the above criteria? Happy to use VBA or formulas but would prefer both.

[image: Points matrix]

Answer (score 2):

By assuming you first row in points in number 14

[image]

Try this formula in cell "F14": `=IF(E14="YES",VLOOKUP(D14,$A$2:$G$11,MATCH(CONCATENATE(C14," +"),$B$1:$G$1,0)+1,FALSE),VLOOKUP(D14,$A$2:$G$11,MATCH(C14,$B$1:$G$1,0),FALSE))`

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this, I prefer using INDEX MATCH, since it is more flexible. The concept is the same.

```
=IF(E14="YES",INDEX($A$1:$G$11,MATCH($D14,$A$1:$A$11,0),MATCH($C14&" +",$A$1:$G$1,0)),INDEX($A$1:$G$11,MATCH($D14,$A$1:$A$11,0),MATCH($C14,$A$1:$G$1,0)))
```

Comment: I agree that `INDEX` / `MATCH` is better but yours is a little verbose for my taste. My two cents... I think it's best to only repeat in the `IF` statement what absolutely has to repeat. I also eliminated unnecessary cells from the lookup ranges which only really matters on a larger scale.
`=INDEX($B$2:$G$11,MATCH(D14,$A$2:$A$11,0),MATCH(C14&IF(E14="YES"," +",""),$B$1:$G$1,0))`

Comment: Nice Mark, you're right, mine wasn't perfect at all. It was a lot easier to just paste the entire formula again with one edit, harder to read though.